# Codename One: receive sms on Android by native code

Tags: android, sms, codenameone

in the Codename One Developers manual, in the section "[Phone functions](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/misc-features.html#_phone_functions)", it's written so:

> Codename One supports sending SMS messages but not receiving them as
>   this functionality isn’t portable. You can send an SMS using:
>   `Display.getInstance().setSMS("+999999999", "My SMS Message");`

My question is if it's possible to receive sms on Android from a specific number. I suppose that it could be possible using [native device functionality in Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tutorial-native-interfaces.html): is it right?

Thank you very much for any help.

P.S.: I know that a workaround to receive text from an external app is [intercepting URL's](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/intercepting-urls-on-ios-android.html), but I'm thinking how to manage the case of a messaging app (that uses SMSes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do that and you probably don't need much to do that. In the case of Android handling incoming SMS would probably require a `BroadcastReciver` which you can just create as a standalone class in the `native/android` directory. The necessary manifest changes can be added via the build hints such as `android.xapplication` & `android.xpermission`.